# Android Animation 'f' meaning

Tags: android

I am confused by the 'f'.

```
ObjectAnimator moveUp = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ivLogo, "translationY", 0f, -150f);
    moveUp.setDuration(1000);
    moveUp.setStartDelay(500);
    moveUp.start();
```

What's the meaning of 'f'?And what's the meaning of form 'of' to '-150f'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a floating point literal.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2

`0f` means that 0 is float

Answer (score 2):

The 'f' means that the -150 is a `float` type, not a value by itself

Answer (score 2):

That **f** is needed because the parameter type the function expects is float. And that is the way of converting 0 (which is integer) to float.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)

Also using **d** and **L** will give you double and long type respectively (just in case if you see them any other place.)